# Internal display freezing on startup with NVIDIA drivers

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, graphics, multiple-monitors, xorg

#### The problem

My internal display freezes on startup. During the boot process, only the internal display works, but right before the login screen it freezes on the ubuntu splash screen. The external display becomes connected and displays the desktop at the moment the internal display stops working.

#### How the issue was caused

After performing the first time set up of the eGPU and the RTX 3070, the entire OS would hang just before the login screen. I.e., the internal display would freeze as described above, and the external display would not show anything. I had to follow [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/), which consisted of adding `nomodeset` as a boot option in grub.

After this, only the internal display was working, even though all current Nvidia drivers were installed. On running `nvidia-smi`, the processes tab showed `No running processes found`. To fix this, I downloaded and ran [this script, 'egpu-switcher'](https://github.com/hertg/egpu-switcher) which changes the `etc/X11/xorg.conf` to (I assume) support running the external display with the eGPU. After performing these steps, upon reboot the internal display freezes as originally described.

#### Solutions tried

- Flash updating BIOS, no effect
- Reinstalling all NVIDIA drivers, no effect
- Installing `bumblebee`, no effect (although I didn't know how to use it)
- Removing `egpu-switcher`, which reverted to previous behaviour where only the internal display was working

#### The solution I want

Either the GPU/NVIDIA drivers to drive the internal display, or the internal display to be powered by my integrated graphics and then my external display to be powered by my dedicated GPU. Is that even possible?

#### My specifications

Ubuntu 20.04
Dell Latitude 7390 (intel integrated graphics)
Razer Core X Chroma eGPU
NVIDIA RTX 3070
Monitor connected to GPU via DisplayPort

#### Other notes

The `nvidia-smi` output is

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.39       Driver Version: 460.39       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 3070    Off  | 00000000:08:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   37C    P8    15W / 220W |    482MiB /  7982MiB |     10%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1601      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 53MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2810      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                231MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2947      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               38MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3423      G   /proc/self/exe                     13MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3667      G   ...AAAAAAAA== --shared-files       30MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8362      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       96MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8793      G   gnome-control-center                3MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm happy to provide any more detail if needed. Thank you to everyone in advance for their answers, I am an Ubuntu novice, so this has been really frustrating me recently.

Comment: +1 Nicely constructed, balanced question and a good example to all. I hope someone can help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by [asking the question on the NVIDIA forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/internal-display-freezing-on-startup-with-egpu/170468). For one reason or another, all I had to do was

- remove `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
- uninstall `egpu-switcher` or run `egpu-switcher cleanup` (if this was already installed/running)
- create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-egpu.conf` with the following only:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia-egpu"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowExternalGpus" "True"
EndSection
```

- then remove the `nomodeset` parameter from the boot options